# Use `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` from NuGet on build agent

Tags: azure-devops, uwp, f#, build-agent

I build a UWP app on Azure DevOps hosted build agent (Windows-2022, version 20220131.1).
Of course, I use `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` NuGet package.
As long as My app has F# code I have to hack a `GateKeeper.xml` and enable F# in it.
So I use PowerShell to do that

```
foreach ($file in gci -Recurse 'C:\Users\*\.nuget\packages\*.net.native.compiler\**\GatekeeperConfig.xml')
{
    (gc $file.FullName) -replace '<FSharpRule on="true">','<FSharpRule on="false">' | sc $file.FullName
}
```

But for version 6.2.12 the content of `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` is present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\` where I have no admin rights to change anything on a build agent.

So I wonder if it is possible to force MSBuild to always use NuGet directly never using packages cached in Program Files?

Answer (score 1):

If the agent and UWP adhere to 'normal' NuGet standards, you could try a [nuget.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) as follows:

```xml
<config>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <!-- any additional sources you need-->
  </packageSources>
  <fallbackPackageFolders>
    <clear />
  </fallbackPackageFolders>
</config>
```

Keep in mind though, that *this might break caching facilities* on agents.